# How to stop click event to continous running JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to stop click() from running after the second .click() how can do that?**
I set the animate() for start 3 second after document ready then use the click() for hide all the elements after use again click() for show all elements again, after that how can I stop click() to run?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout(anim,3000);

        function anim(){
            $('#box1, #box3').animate({width:600+'px'}, 4000, 'easeOutExpo');
            $('#box2').fadeIn(4000);
            $('#btn').animate({left:'+=50px', opacity: '1'}, 2000);
        }

        $('#btn').click(function(){
            $('#box1, #box3').animate({width:0+'px'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
            $('#box2').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#btn').click(function(){
                    $('#box1, #box3').animate({width:600+'px'}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
                    $('#box2').fadeIn(2000);
                });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why are you nesting events..why ..why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest events.

Try

[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) documentation.

```
function handler1() { //first click code
    $('#box1, #box3').animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
    $('#box2').fadeOut(1000);
    $(this).one("click", handler2); //set second click code
}
function handler2() { //second click code
    $('#box1, #box3').animate({
        width: 600 + 'px'
    }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
    $('#box2').fadeIn(2000);
    //$(this).one("click", handler1); // you can un-comment if you want to loop click1 and click2
};
$('#btn').one('click', handler1);//first click
```